# Preview in OSX El Capitan defaults to 100% scale

Tags: preview, printing, graphics

When printing a jpeg, preview now defaults to 100% scale, which is not what I want. I am having to manually select scale to fit and fill entire paper. How can I make it always default to the latter (as it used to in previous versions of OSX)?

Answer (score 1):

In the Preview Preferences, you can define the 100% scale.  In Preview press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>, then click on the *Images* tab.  You will get two options

- 1 image pixel equals 1 screen pixel
- Size on screen equals size on printout

[image]

Select the second one.